# TObjectIntMap (Trove 3) How can 'int get(java.lang.Object key)' method return null? Is it a documentation mistake?

Tags: java, trove4j

I have been looking into the documentation of Trove4j library. Particularly the `TObjectIntMap` interface. According to the documentation of the library the get method returns `null` if the key is not present in the map. The documentation I am referring to can be seen here:

http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/TObjectIntMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29

At the time of reading (27/02/2014) the documentation states

> `int get(java.lang.Object key)`
> "Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key."

#### My question is:

How is it possible for the method to return `null` when the return type is the primitive `int`. As far as I know it is only possible for `Integer` references to be `null`. Is it a documentation error?

Comment: I noticed the same yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, `int` can't be null. Thus their documentation is inconsistent.

To give you a bit of insight how Trove is built: they have templates for all primitive and object permutations of datastructures, so it is understandable that you can't keep everything consistent. You should report this to the project however so they can fix that.

To check if there is a value for a key, you should use the method

```
public boolean containsKey(java.lang.Object key)
```

or (a more hacky solution) is to check for the default value for no entries:

```
gnu.trove.impl.Constants.DEFAULT_INT_NO_ENTRY_VALUE
```

which defaults to 0, if you didn't override the `gnu.trove.no_entry.int` property.